# правильный редирект на HTTPS с условием домена

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl, домен

Один сайт имеет три домена. На главный домен приобрел SLL сертификат, для автоматической переадресации я делаю редирект:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Как здесь прописать условие, чтобы редирект действовал только для главного домена? ибо для других доменов у меня нет сертификата SLL - а редирект автоматический..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ещё актуально - добавь ещё одно условие, которое проверит имя сайта. Примерно так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.сайт1.com [NC]
```